# Falha de autenticação usando OkHttp e Bearer Token no Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Spring Boot que faz requisições HTTP a uma API externa usando OkHttp. Esta api utiliza de autenticação via token Bearer.

Embora a autenticação funcione perfeitamente quando testada com ferramentas como Postman e Insomnia, estou enfrentando problemas ao tentar autenticar usando OkHttp3 no Spring Boot. Recebo um erro 401 Unauthorized, sugerindo que o token de autenticação não está sendo enviado corretamente ou não é reconhecido pela API.

Aqui está a classe do meu código que realiza a requisição:

```
package com.cronsegmarket.app.infra;

import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level;

public class WebClientSegCam {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebClientSegCam.class);

    private final String URL_SEG_CAM = "https://segcam.segmarket.com.br/zm/api/";
    private final String USER_SEG_CAM = "dashapi";
    private final String PSW_SEG_CAM = "g4Qv2sLJ759w";

    private static final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    private static String buildUrl(String baseUrl, int monitorId, String startTime, String endTime) {
        return String.format("%s/MonitorId:%d/StartTime >=:%s/EndTime <=:%s.json", baseUrl, monitorId, startTime,
                endTime);
    }

    public JSONArray findEvents(String token, int monitorId, String startTime, String endTime) throws Exception {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor inter = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        inter.setLevel(Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(inter).connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        String url = buildUrl(URL_SEG_CAM + "events/index", monitorId, startTime, endTime);

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).method("GET", null)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {

            String resposta = URLDecoder.decode(response.body().string(), "UTF-8");

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                logger.error(resposta);
                throw new Exception(resposta);
            }

            return new JSONArray(resposta);
        }
    }

    public JSONArray findAllMonitors(String token) throws Exception {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor inter = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        inter.setLevel(Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(inter).connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL_SEG_CAM + "monitors.json").get()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {

            String resposta = URLDecoder.decode(response.body().string(), "UTF-8");

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                logger.error(resposta);
                throw new Exception(resposta);
            }

            return new JSONArray(resposta);
        }
    }

    public JSONObject authSegCam() throws Exception {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor inter = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        inter.setLevel(Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(inter).connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create("user=" + USER_SEG_CAM + "&pass=" + PSW_SEG_CAM + "&stateful=1",
                mediaType);

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL_SEG_CAM + "host/login.json")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(body).build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            String resposta = URLDecoder.decode(response.body().string(), "UTF-8");

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                logger.error(resposta);
                throw new Exception(resposta);
            }

            return new JSONObject(resposta);
        }
    }

    public JSONObject refreshAuthSegCam(String refreshToken) throws Exception {
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create("token=" + refreshToken + "&stateful=1", mediaType);

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL_SEG_CAM + "/host/login.json").post(body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            String resposta = URLDecoder.decode(response.body().string(), "UTF-8");

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                logger.error(resposta);
                throw new Exception(resposta);
            }

            return new JSONObject(resposta);
        }
    }
}
```

Segue o código client gerado pelo insonia:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "user=dashapi&stateful=1&pass=g4Qv2sLJ759w");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://segcam.segmarket.com.br/zm/api/host/login.json")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .addHeader("User-Agent", "insomnia/8.6.1")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();


OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://segcam.segmarket.com.br/zm/api/monitors.json")
  .get()
  .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJab25lTWluZGVyIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA5ODQyMDY0LCJleHAiOjE3MDk4NDkyNjQsInVzZXIiOiJkYXNoYXBpIiwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.CXimEUhaJJ5mDws9rQw0AE48SI5iPBr3xSiIFYqDPao")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://segcam.segmarket.com.br/zm/api/events/index/MonitorId:2/StartTime%20%3E=:2024-03-05%2018:14:19/EndTime%20%3C=:2024-03-07%2018:14:19.json")
  .get()
  .addHeader("User-Agent", "insomnia/8.6.1")
  .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJab25lTWluZGVyIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA5ODUzNzEyLCJleHAiOjE3MDk4NjA5MTIsInVzZXIiOiJkYXNoYXBpIiwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.2kh3UdjozqRWEpMKRqRF5SVso6fpO13dsh_WW6xl9hQ")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Verifiquei se o token está correto e não está expirado, autenticando via o código e testando via insonia.
Tentei encodar o token manualmente para verificar problemas de codificação, autenticando via insonia e testando manualmente o token no okhttp3.
Revisei as configurações de segurança da API para assegurar que não há bloqueios por IP ou outros.

Existe alguma configuração específica do OkHttp para autenticação Bearer que eu possa estar perdendo?
Poderia haver alguma configuração no Spring Boot que interfira na maneira como as requisições são enviadas?
Qualquer ajuda para resolver esse problema seria muito apreciada. Obrigado!

O que tentei:

Validação do Token: Garanti que o token de autenticação é válido e não expirado usando-o em uma requisição do Postman para o mesmo endpoint da API, que teve sucesso.

Verificação de Token Codificado: Para eliminar quaisquer problemas de geração dinâmica de tokens, codifiquei diretamente no cabeçalho da requisição um token previamente bem-sucedido.

Depuração: Habilitei o registro de HTTP no OkHttp para inspecionar a requisição de saída e verificar se o cabeçalho de Autorização está corretamente incluído e formatado.

Revisão da Configuração do Spring Boot: Investiguei quaisquer configurações do Spring Boot que possam interferir com as requisições HTTP, incluindo configurações de segurança que possam remover cabeçalhos ou alterar requisições.

O que eu esperava:

Dado que o token funciona no Postman e Insomnia, eu esperava que o mesmo token autorizasse a requisição quando enviada via cliente OkHttp na minha aplicação Spring Boot. Especificamente, eu antecipava:

Um status de resposta HTTP bem-sucedido (200 OK) da API.

Acesso aos recursos ou dados assim como no insonia.

Comment: Problema resolvido com a atualização da API.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.